# How to alert a message in notification area of Android using JQuery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have developed a tiny browser-based app using Jquery and PhP for Android mobile. How can I alert a message in notification area (top of the screen where I can see the message if app main page is not visible) saying something like "The Process Completed". I don't want to interrupt user, just as a notification or reminder in top of the screen. 
Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to use Phonegap AND  the [Status Bar Notification plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification)

Comment: I don't want to use phonegap. Can I do use the plugin without phonegap?

Comment: It's important that you understand that this is a Browser Restriction. If you want to use the native browser to display your app, there is no way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the notification panel **outside** of the browser on the home screen? If your app is just browser based, I'm afraid you have no chance to access anything outside of the browser window.

There are solutions to access such features, a popular example being **[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)** but I'm not sure if the notification functionality is part of it.